# How to format an f32 with a specific precision and prepended zeros?

Tags: floating-point, formatting, rust

What format string should I use in the `println!` macro in order to print `0.0` as `00000.000`?

```
println!("={:05.3}", 0.0);
```

Output: `=0.000`

Expected: `=00000.000`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first number (after the zero) is the **total** number of characters.

So you **do** display your number with 5 characters. If you want to have 5 numbers before the dot, you must type:

```
println!("{:09.3}", 123.45);
```

Output: `00123.450`

Because 9 minus 3 minus the dot = 5 digits.